# What is fuser and why is it so processor hungry?

Tags: cpu-load

My computer became too slow and according to `top` fuser is consuming all available cpu time.

What the hell is that? What do I have to do get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fuser` is a command. From `man fuser`:

> Identify processes using files or sockets.
>
> fuser displays the PIDs of processes using the specified files or  file systems.   In the default display mode, each file name is followed by a letter denoting the type of access:

You can track down the process from command line with

`ps -ef |grep fuser`

It will show a `pid` and a `ppid` if you follow that number you should be able to track down the program that issued it (and by what user and by what terminal).

Or as said in a comment by Lakritsbollar use `pstree`. It does exactly what it claims: make a tree of ps ;) :

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ pstree
init─┬─NetworkManager─┬─dhclient
     │                └─2*[{NetworkManager}]
     ├─accounts-daemon───{accounts-daemo}
     ├─acpid
     ├─atd
     ├─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
     ├─bamfdaemon───{bamfdaemon}
     ├─bluetoothd
     ├─chromium-browse─┬─chromium-browse───{chromium-brows}
     │                 ├─chromium-browse───6*[{chromium-brows}]
     │                 └─18*[{chromium-brows}]
     ├─chromium-browse───8*[chromium-browse───4*[{chromium-brows}]]
```

Do you perhaps have a terminal open somewhere (on tty1 ... tty6)?

iirc fuser is owned by `root` and therefor will get all the attention it needs.

Oh and if you did not start it yourself... don't mess with it and only track down the program that started it.

Comment: Resizing your terminal window to be really large and issuing `pstree` is a bit easier than to search for the pids and ppids, IMHO. :-)

Comment: fine Ill edit it in ;)

Comment: Yes, I did have a terminal. I'm using guake, btw.